# Nullable anonymous record

Tags: f#

Based on a condition, i want to assign either an anonymous record or `null` to a variable.

For example

```
            let cryptoParameters =
                match status with
                | Some cryptoParameters ->
                    {| SecretSalt = cryptoParameters.SecretSalt
                       PublicIdentityKey = cryptoParameters.PublicIdentityKey
                       PrivateIdentityKey = cryptoParameters.PrivateIdentityKey |}
                | _ -> null
```

I keep getting the following error:

`error FS0043: The type '{| PrivateIdentityKey: string; SecretSalt: string; PublicIdentityKey: string |}' does not have 'null' as a proper value`

Answer (score 3):

You can get `null` values by using `Unchecked.defaultof`. In the case of an anonymous type. You must provide the whole anonymous definition as an pamarameter like:

```
let x = Unchecked.defaultof<{|Name:string; Age:int|}>
```

in your case. The compiler can infer the type, and you can use underscore instead.

```
let isEven x = x % 2 = 0

let person =
    match isEven 3 with
    | true  -> {Name="David"; Age=100}
    | false -> Unchecked.defaultof<_>
```

But maybe you want to use the `Option` type instead of using `null`. That's the way how F# handles `null`. Because `null` is usally prohibited by F#.

If you have a problem because `Option` is a reference type, and it causes some kind of performance problems, then maybe you want to use the `ValueOption` type instead.

See additionally information on Option like:

[Microsoft - Null Values in F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/values/null-values)
[Microsoft - Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/options)
[Microsoft - Value Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/value-options)
[F# for Fun and Profit - The Option Type](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/)

Comment: Since all branches of a `match` expression must have the same type, the compiler can infer it: `Unchecked.defaultof<_>` should work. But I definitely agree with using optional types instead, value or reference, unless you are doing interop with C#.

Comment: The reason why I would like to have a `nullable` anonymous type is, I am using a custom json serializer. The `Person` is carried in `Optional` type in the program. However, during the serialization, i have to set the related parameter to a null (in case of None) or anonymous type.

Comment: @sardok Maybe there is another solution how you solve it with serialization. Anyway i have updated the answer. dumetrulo gave a hint for the solution.

Comment: @DavidRaab Thanks.